# WithSpinner not reloading with Dashboardpage

Tags: r

I am using `withSpinner` with `dashboardpage` and I have the following problem:

I have two different `tabitems`:

- The first has a `selectInput` object.
- The second has a plot depending on the first.

The loading spinner appears only the first time the plot is calculated, therefore if I go back to the first page and change the value in the `selectinput` when I return to the plot page the spinner does not appear.

Here an example:

Here a small example:

ui <- dashboardPage(skin="black",
              dashboardHeader(title ="ciao",titleWidth=460),
              dashboardSidebar(
                sidebarMenu(
                  menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard", icon=icon("globe",lib = "glyphicon")),
                  menuItem("Plot", tabName = "plot", icon=icon("th-list", lib = "glyphicon")))),
                dashboardBody(
                  tabItems(
                    tabItem(tabName="Dashboard",
                            selectInput("select", "select:", choices = c(1:4), selected = 1)),
                    tabItem(tabName="plot",
                            withSpinner(plotOutput("plot"))))))

server <- function(input,output){

output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p <- plot(mtcars[as.numeric(input$select),])
    p
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some example code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thankyou, I added a small example.